# Redis or SQL Server to store SMS confirmation data

Tags: sql-server, redis

I'm building an HTTP API that have an endpoint for sending SMS to verify the identity of users.

I'm wondering if i should use SQL Server or Redis. Redis it's a lot faster, and i'm thinking in the possibility of discarding the SMS confirmation data after some minutes, as Redis support this out-of-the-box.

Will SQL Server be fast enough for this task?
Or it's better to use Redis, taking into account that i won't need the sms verification data in the future anyway (that can be a wrong assumption).

I'm needing some insight in this question, anyway.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing you're storing is this data, and only for a short period if time, SQL seems like overkill. As far as speed goes, either should be more than fast enough to store the data; it's just probably easier to evict the records from redis. But really either should be fine.

Comment: I decided to use Redis as cache for this, so anyway SQL Server will be used to store permanently the sms data.